# change the text color of ion-button

Tags: ionic-framework

As per question, how can I change the color of the text inside ion-button? Here's the code for my button

```
<button ion-button block (click) = "submitForm()">Submit</button>
```

I've tried various methods like below

```
<button ion-button block (click) = "submitForm()"><sub ion-text color = "light">Submit</sub></button>

<button ion-button block (click) = "submitForm()" ion-text color = "light">Submit</button>

<button ion-button block (click) = "submitForm()"><span ion-text color = "light">Submit</span></button>

<button ion-button block (click) = "submitForm()" class= "font-white">Submit</button>
```

where in the last example above I put in `.font-white{color: #fff !important;}` inside `app.scss`

but nothing works.

Comment: in your question u put `style` attribute which is invalid..you have to give class name. I edited your question.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the `style` attribute from button give `class` name and then in your `app.scss` but below code(assume u give class name as `font-white`)

```
 .font-white
  {  
    color : #fff !important; 
   }
```

Comment: As you can see from my question above, I've already done this

Answer (score 0):

Modify your **component.html** and **component.scss** file in following way,

```
<button ion-button block (click)="submitForm()" class="custom-button">Submit</button>
```

In your **component.scss**,

```
.custom-button{
  color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine in ionic-4:-

```
<button ion-button block class="font-white">Submit</button>
```

In appcomponent.scss

```
.font-white {
    color: #fff;
  }
```

For Ionic-5:-

```
 <ion-button class="font-white">Submit</ion-button>
```

in scss file

```
  .font-white {
    --color: #fff;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want white color only then do not create any of scss class
just write

```
<ion-button fill="clear" class="text-white" (click)="btnClickFN()">
        save
      </ion-button>
```

else if you want to give custom color then please make class in `.scss`
it will apply on all the tag where you wrote `<ion-button></ion-button>` tag

```
ion-button{
color: #00FF00; // green color
}
```

else you can give color only in specific one button then please create customclass like below in file of
`.sccs`

```
.btnColor{
  color: #00FF00; // Green color
 }
```

in `.html` file::
just put class inside `<ion-button>`  tag and give name as u give in `.scss` file

```
 <ion-button fill="clear" class="btnColor" (click)="btnClickFN()">
            save
          </ion-button>
```

Comment: Please change color code whatever you need